# Display message on Android TV sent over network

Tags: notifications, networking, android-tv, popup

I have several Android TV boxes driving TVs in my house.  I switched them over from Kodi.

I used to send a message to Kodi (using Netcat) from a Linux box that runs a phone system.  When a call arrived, my Kodi boxes would display "Incoming call from Bob 1-234-567-8902".

Kodi had a native API for displaying messages.  Does Android TV?  If not, is there a way to display messages sent over the network, possibly an app?

P.S. I'm not asking for "the best app" - just is this possible and ideally example apps that can do so.  I found that I can write my own Android program (per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316862/display-a-message-on-android)) but hoping not to code something when not needed.